# Run html file from google cloud url

Tags: c#, html, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I have saved my html file into google cloud storage with public read permission.
When I am trying to open html file, Chrome automatically downloads the HTML files locally and does not open it in a browser tab.

Html public url is:
https://www.googleapis.com/download/storage/v1/b/presentationpublish/o/index_1112q_252_636703629560463983.html?generation=1534766167109567&alt=media

code:

```
return storage.UploadObject(
       bucket: BucketName,
       objectName: objectName,
       contentType: "text/html",
       source: valStream,
       options: new UploadObjectOptions { PredefinedAcl = publicRead }
   );
```

Comment: you can set chrome to open [files](https://ccm.net/faq/36268-google-chrome-how-to-clear-auto-opening-settings)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution, we can change the current url with new like:

```
var url=https://www.googleapis.com/download/storage/v1/b/presentationpublish/o/index_1112q_252_636703629560463983.html?generation=1534766167109567&alt=media

var new_url=url.replace("https://www.googleapis.com/download/storage/v1/b/", "https://storage.googleapis.com/").replace("/o/", "/");
```

Now it's working fine for me.