# HTML page (Mochawesome Report) doesn't load on Google Cloud?

Tags: automated-tests, google-cloud-storage, mochawesome

I'm running API tests using GitHub Actions and I want to upload to the report generated by Mochawesome to Google Cloud so I can see failures clearly without digging through CI logs. I have the upload part working but when I view the html file on Google Cloud it doesn't load, I just get a blank white page. I'm uploading the css files too so why isn't the html file loading?

[image]
[image]

Comment: George, please let me know if the below recommendations were helpful.

Comment: I resolved it using my own solution because none others had been posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using cdn for assets resolves the isssue `.mocharc.js`:

```
module.exports = {
    reporter: 'node_modules/mochawesome',
    'reporter-option': [
        'cdn=true',
        'timestamp=true'    
    ],
};
```

Answer (score 0):

When you're creating a file using the [Cloud Storage API](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/googlestorage/overview#Using_Google_Storage) , set the mime_type to 'text/html' and skip the content_disposition.
You can manually edit the metadata to set the proper type, which is text/css for CSS files. If the type is neither specified nor auto-detected at upload time, [Google Cloud Storage serves files as binary/octet-stream](https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/reference-headers#contenttype) which may prevent the browser from properly rendering it.
Alternatively, you can also specify the MIME type in HTML, e.g.,

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/theme.css" type="text/css">`
to make sure that the browser handles it appropriately.

Here are a few examples with similar implementation:

1. [Run HTML file from Google Cloud URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51930389/run-html-file-from-google-cloud-url)
2. [Serve HTML file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65652420/serve-html-directly-from-google-cloud-storage-and-resolve-relative-links)
3. [Website host HTML file page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53167425/google-cloud-platform-host-website-but-only-working-for-index-html)